# Tf-IDF vectorized data won't work with naive bayes classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf

I have the following python code that I am using after preprocessing the data where data has to columns, one is the label either positive or negative and the other has tweet texts.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data['Tweet'], data['Label'], test_size=0.20, random_state=0)
tf_idf = TfidfVectorizer()

x_traintf = tf_idf.fit_transform(X_train)
x_traintf = tf_idf.transform(X_train)
x_testtf = tf_idf.fit_transform(X_test)
x_testtf = tf_idf.transform(X_test)

naive_bayes_classifier = MultinomialNB()
naive_bayes_classifier.fit(x_traintf, y_train)
y_pred = naive_bayes_classifier.predict(x_testtf)
print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_pred, target_names=['pos', 'neg']))
```

Here is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 72, in <module>
    naive_bayes_classifier.fit(x_traintf, y_train)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 749, in fit
    X, y = self._check_X_y(X, y)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 583, in _check_X_y
    return self._validate_data(X, y, accept_sparse="csr", reset=reset)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 565, in _validate_data
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 1122, in check_X_y
    y = _check_y(y, multi_output=multi_output, y_numeric=y_numeric, estimator=estimator)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 1144, in _check_y
    _assert_all_finite(y, input_name="y", estimator_name=estimator_name)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 111, in _assert_all_finite
    raise ValueError("Input contains NaN")
ValueError: Input contains NaN
```

I've tried this as well but got similar results:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(all_X, all_y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42) 
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X_train_tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)
clf = MultinomialNB() 
clf.fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)
X_test_tfidf = vectorizer.transform(X_test)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test_tfidf)
print(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

edit: I've used `data.dropna(inplace=True)` and it appears to think that my strings are null because they are in Arabic.

Comment: The error is quite clear, you have null data. How you deal with it, is another subject.For example: https://towardsdatascience.com/7-ways-to-handle-missing-values-in-machine-learning-1a6326adf79e

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first of all, there must be some confusion around what the methods do because they are being used wrong. There might a chance that this is the issue.

Method `.fit_transform()` will fit to the data but also transform in place, it is like calling `fit()` and then `transform()`. Have a look at the documentation for more clarity: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform

Your code, for the transformation of the data, should be something like the following:

```py
tf_idf = TfidfVectorizer()

x_traintf = tf_idf.fit_transform(X_train)
x_testtf = tf_idf.transform(X_test)
```

You only fit and learn the train data, and transform the train and test data with that learning. Your original code, was actually transforming the train data twice, and learning from the test data again and transforming twice also.

Do let me know if this is the issue. It might be that this double transformation caused issues. Please print the output after using the transformer, to see the output of the train and test data (features).